# extracting field error from JSON

Tags: jquery, json

I have a JSON being returned from the server that looks like this:

```
{
    "fieldErrors": [{
        "name": "content",
        "status": "The file 2015 Shift Schedule.xlsx exceeds the maximum file size: 51200 bytes."
    }]
}
```

Using Ajax I need to extract the value of status.

This is what I have so far, but it isn't giving me what I want:

```
$.ajax({
     url: '../jsp/uploadfiletodb.jsp',
     type: 'POST',
     data: formData,
     async: false,
     cache: false,
     contentType: false,
     processData: false,
     success: function (returndata) {
     //handle any fieldErrors
     var json_obj = $.parseJSON(returndata);  //parse JSON
     $.each(json_obj, function(key,value) {
       alert(value.fieldErrors.status);
     });               
   }
```

It keeps telling me "TypeError: value.fieldErrors is undefined".  How do I access the status value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to loop is not an array. It **is** the object. Use this instead:

```
$.ajax({
  url: '../jsp/uploadfiletodb.jsp',
  type: 'POST',
  data: formData,
  async: false,
  cache: false,
  contentType: false,
  processData: false,
  success: function (returndata) {
    //handle any fieldErrors
    var json_obj = $.parseJSON(returndata);  //parse JSON
    // You are not iterating a loop.
    alert(json_obj.fieldErrors[0].status);
  }
});
```

Or if you want to loop through the errors, then you need to use:

```
$.ajax({
  url: '../jsp/uploadfiletodb.jsp',
  type: 'POST',
  data: formData,
  async: false,
  cache: false,
  contentType: false,
  processData: false,
  success: function (returndata) {
    //handle any fieldErrors
    var json_obj = $.parseJSON(returndata);  //parse JSON
    // Looping through the errors
    $.each(json_obj.fieldErrors, function (index, value) {
      alert(value.status);
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: fieldErrors is an array itself, it should be json_obj.fieldErrors[0].status

Comment: The first one gave me 'undefined', but the second example worked.  Thanks for the assistance.